# For loop outout numbers to a string

Tags: python, string, function, for-loop

Well i just wrote a code that get's a starting number, ending number and a step (it's a range) and prints all numbers in bettwen.
It works great but i want the output to be also as a string.

This is my code:

```
def count(num1,num2,steps):
    getfirstnum=int(raw_input(num1))
    getsecondenum=int(raw_input(num2))
    getsteps=int(raw_input(steps))
    for num in range(getfirstnum,getsecondenum,getsteps):
        print 'in bettwen: ',num
    return num

def Main():

    Getnum=count('Give me the 1st number: ','Give me the 2nd number: ','How many Steps?: ')


if __name__ == "__main__":
    Main()
```

Now if i will insert:
1st number: 1
2nd number: 10
Step: 2

I will get the result:

```
in bettwen:  1
in bettwen:  3
in bettwen:  5
in bettwen:  7
in bettwen:  9
```

How can i make my output to be a string?
Thanks.

Comment: Your output is a string.  Are you saying you want to return the output as a string instead of printing it?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
def whatever(start, stop):
    result = ''
    for num in range(start,stop):
        result += str(num)
    return result

print(whatever(0,5))
```

---

```
01234
```

Comment: local variable 'result' referenced before assignment

Comment: @ShaiAlfasi - if this worked for you, please accept it as the answer

Answer (score 0):

```
def count(num1,num2,steps):
    string_output = ""
    getfirstnum=int(raw_input(num1))
    getsecondenum=int(raw_input(num2))
    getsteps=int(raw_input(steps))
    for num in range(getfirstnum,getsecondenum,getsteps):
        string_output += str(num)
    return string_output
```

Comment: TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'int' objects

Comment: @ShaiAlfasi Updated the answer. changed `num` to `str(num)`

Answer (score 0):

```
...
print 'in bettwen: ' + str(num)
...
```

Or if you are looking for something different like:

```
string = 'in bettwen: '
for num in range(getfirstnum,getsecondenum,getsteps):
    string += " " + str(num)
return num
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `join` and a generator:

```
>>> ''.join(str(n) for n in range(1,10,2))
'13579'
```

This is the equivalent of:

```
>>> s = ''
>>> for n in range(1,10,2):
...     s += str(n)
...     
>>> s
'13579'
```